# Angular dynamic form, sub-components not updating top level form

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

As the title suggests, I've created a dynamic form using a mix of tutorials I've read. 
I have a parent component which creates a empty form group which I then (try) to populate with sub-groups via child components. These components are passed a reference to the parent form, and the child component then creates its own formgroup and attempts to bind this to the parent.

The form model should then look like the following:

`FormGroup
-- FormGroup1
---- FormControl1
---- FormControl2
-- FormGroup2
---- FormControl3
---- FormControl4`

However, even thought the lower level form controls all render, the parent form doesn't seem to know they exist. My issue seems like it might be related to [Angular 2: How to link form elements across a dynamically created components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399022/angular-2-how-to-link-form-elements-across-a-dynamically-created-components) but I was unable to figure out what he actually did to fix his issue.

Any thoughts?

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imi6j6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Wow... I just figured it out.

I was trying to add my subgroups to the parent via just assigning properties, but I should have been using `FormGroup.addControl(new <FormGroup>)`.

Works perfectly now.